# SQL - Case when using two date columns

Tags: sql

I am trying to write a case statement in SQL to allow me to separate out new employees from tenured employees based on when they received a contact from a customer.

I have two date columns, the day they started work and the day they received a contact.

This is what I'm aiming for:

```
CASE WHEN start_date is equal or within 70 days of Contact_day THEN 'New Hire'
     WHEN start_date is after 70 days of Contact_day THEN 'Tenured' 
END AS Agent_tenure
```

I'm not sure how  to write this out in SQL. Could somebody help me please.

Comment: Well, what database is this for?  Please show sample data table and expected output.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Their date handling functions all differ.

Answer (score 1):

Believe you using sql-server

```
Select (Case when start_date <= DATEADD(DAY,70,Contact_day) then 'NewHire'
        else 'Tenured' end) as Agent_tenure
From Tablename
```